# 'bytes' object has no attribute 'oid'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto, pycryptodome

my code has an error in line 14 saying bytes object has no attribute oid. I am not sure why is it giving me this error.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA
from Crypto.Signature import DSS
import random
import os

def generate_dsa_key_pair(bits=1024):
    """Generates a DSA key pair with the given number of bits."""
    key = DSA.generate(bits)
    return key

def sign_text(text, key):
    """Signs the given text using the given DSA private key."""
    signer = DSS.new(key, 'fips-186-3')
    **signature = signer.sign(text.encode())**
    return signature

def create_p2ms_script(n, m):
    """Creates a P2MS script using the given number of public keys and signatures."""
    # Generate N DSA key pairs
    keys = [generate_dsa_key_pair() for i in range(n)]

    # Select M private keys from the N keys
    priv_keys = random.sample(keys, m)

    # Generate M signatures using the private keys
    signatures = [sign_text("help me", priv_key) for priv_key in priv_keys]

    # Create scriptPubKey by concatenating the N public keys
    scriptPubKey = b''.join([key.publickey().export_key(format='DER') for key in keys])

    # Create scriptSig by concatenating the M signatures
    scriptSig = b''.join(signatures)

    return scriptPubKey, scriptSig

def save_script_to_file(script, filename):
    """Saves the given script to the specified file."""
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(script)

def execute_p2ms_script(scriptPubKey, scriptSig):
    """Executes the given P2MS script by verifying the signatures using the public keys."""
    # Split scriptPubKey into individual public keys
    pub_keys = [DSA.import_key(key) for key in scriptPubKey.split(b'\x00\x02\x81\x81') if key]

    # Split scriptSig into individual signatures
    signatures = [sig for sig in scriptSig.split(b'\x00\x02\x81\x81') if sig]

    # Check if the number of signatures matches the number of public keys
    if len(signatures) != len(pub_keys):
        return False

    # Verify each signature using the corresponding public key
    for i, sig in enumerate(signatures):
        verifier = DSS.new(pub_keys[i], 'fips-186-3')
        if not verifier.verify("help me ".encode(), sig):
            return False

    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input("Enter the number of public keys (N): "))
    m = int(input("Enter the number of signatures (M): "))

    # Create P2MS script
    scriptPubKey, scriptSig = create_p2ms_script(n, m)

    # Save script
```

I have tried to hash the object but then my code wouldn't work. I have bolded the line, can someone please explain to me?

for context, my code is meant to replicate a P2MS function.

edit: the full traceback is as follows:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'bytes' object has no attribute 'oid'
File ", line 14, in sign_text signature = signer.sign(text.encode())
File , line 26, in <listcomp> signatures = [sign_text("help me", priv_key) for priv_key in priv_keys]
File , line 26, in create_p2ms_script signatures = [sign_text("help me", priv_key) for priv_key in priv_keys]
File , line 66, in <module> scriptPubKey, scriptSig = create_p2ms_script(n, m)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'oid'
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. As it is we have no way of telling what line is even triggering the error.

Comment: Hi @kindall, thank you for replying, i have added in the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

The `bytes` object is what's returned by `text.encode()`. It's a UTF-8 encoded string and it does not have an attribute `oid`.

That is not what `DSS.sign(msg_hash)` expects. It expects a hash object (which conveniently has an attribute `oid`), see also [PyCryptoDome doc on sign](https://www.pycryptodome.org/src/signature/dsa#Crypto.Signature.DSS.DssSigScheme.sign). So a `Crypto.Hash` object has to be created first as described [here](https://www.pycryptodome.org/src/hash/hash):

```py
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

# ... line 14
hash_object = SHA256.new(data=text.encode())
signature = signer.sign(hash_object)
```

In your question, you said that passing a hash object did not work. However, that's the proper way to do it. You cannot make a wish on an API and expect things to work. See the API as a contract. It specifies what you need to give and what you get in return.

Make your code run without throwing exceptions. Once you're there and you still encounter errors after passing a hash, please post another question. A thorough explanation of expected and actual behavior beyond "would not work" would also be helpful.